# In App Purchase stopped working (error code 109)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

When today I tested my `In-App purchases` again (on a device) it gives me the following error (when I fetch the available products of my app):

Cannot connect to iTunes Store `(Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=109 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x8d97830 {SSErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=503, NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store})`

The code worked fine before.

Anyone got this error too?

Comment: I am getting same issue. While I have test application with different Application and Products.

Answer (score 7):

Follow the status here on Apple's forums: https://devforums.apple.com/message/933555#933555

Comment: Looks like the above link is broken

Answer (score 1):

1) On the first device I also got this error while requesting SCProducs in the sandbox environment.

2)I have tried to request SCProducs from another device. This error hadn't appeared.

3)After that on the first device I have "Erased All Content and Settings" logged in and out from the real "iTues & App Store" account, launched the app and this error hadn't occurred.
(Maybe just coincidence)

!!! Interesting investigation. After I set the Date & Time for an hour earlier (on another device - for a day earlier) the SKProducts come as they have to.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, which corrected when I set my iPad's date one day into the future. Perhaps something to do with the release date online being after the local date on the iPad?