# iOS IAP (in-app purchase) Fails to Work in Japanese and Russian environment

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am testing `IAP` on my `iPad/iOS7`, everything work, then I switch my `iPad` to Japanese and Russian environment, `IAP` doesn't work then, always returns "failed transaction", I checked the codes and everything should be fine, does `IAP` testing only work in English environment??

Comment: I'm not sure about it only working in English, but over the past week there have been some problems with the IAP sandbox. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092887/in-app-purchase-stopped-working-error-code-109 and this Apple discussions thread: https://devforums.apple.com/message/933555#933555 (requires dev login)

Comment: oh, maybe that is the reason, since it fails to work sometimes in English environment, I just want to see if IAP testing work in other language too.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to go over the following check list:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you test in-apps you use one of your ITC test user accounts which is usually tied to definite Itunes store country.
May be it can be the main cause.