# Cannot connect to iTunes Store error while IAP

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, xcode7

Mode : SandBox
Certificate : Developer certificate
P File:
   developer provisioning profile

I am planning to integrate IAP so I added sandbox id in iTunesConnect. When I try to execute the code I'm getting below error:

> Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=109 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
>   UserInfo=usrinfo {SSErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=403,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://www.igeeksblog.com/cannot-connect-to-itunes-store/

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... mentioned way is not resolving the issue

Comment: you are facing the same issue again

Comment: Yes ... Always calling (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error delegate

Comment: What code are you using to make the request?

Comment: Thanks for the response my code was correct. its network issue ... just removed the firewall production and white list the ip for device will be work ...

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092887/in-app-purchase-stopped-working-error-code-109 ?

Comment: Answer is here ... please check comments on below link http://www.28im.com/ios/a3354079.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error description includes a useful hint.

```
SSErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey = 403
```

It it error **403**. Status code [403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) responses are the result of the web server being configured to deny access, for some reason, to the requested resource by the client.

There might be a proxy server or other configuration on the network you're connected to that prevents you from accessing the store. Try using different network and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Importantly, 403 forbids access independent of authentication. 401 means your credentials are wrong, and providing the right credentials fixes the problem. 403 means "there's no way we let you go there".